# Unable to resolve 500.30 error in simple web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-6.0, windows-server-2022

##### Error

I just created a new Razor Pages website. It's simple and only has a couple of page. But the site is failing with the following message.

[image]

##### Event Viewer

I see the event viewer is reporting errors.

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scwebgroup.com' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/7/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\scwebgroup.com' failed to load coreclr. Exception message: CLR worker thread exited prematurely

##### Error Logging

I set `stdoutLogEnabled` to true in web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\SCWebGroup.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 43bcc2f4-878c-4b9a-903b-16d6bf867dc5-->
```

But I can find no log folder or any log files.

##### Running from the Command Line

I read you can try running the application from the command line and any errors might be shown, so I tried that. But when I ran the application, no errors were reported. It appeared to run correctly.

[image]

##### Target Version of .NET

My app is targeting .NET 6.0 and I have other applications that target .NET 6.0 on this same server. So I know this version of .NET is installed.

##### Summary

The application runs fine when I run it within Visual Studio.

The new application does not access any database.

I'm out of ideas. Can anyone offer other things to try here?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @JuanR: I'm not sure I know how to debug remotely.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed error information.

Comment: Are you compiling for Any CPU, 32 bit or 64 bit? Try compiling for 64 bit, see if that solves your issue.

Comment: @JuanR: Do'h! Yes, this was the issue. Setting it to x64 solved the issue! Many thanks!

Comment: @JonathanWood great. Happy to help. I will post an answer. I would appreciate it if you mark it as accepted.

Comment: You omitted how you generated the binaries (the parameters set for `dotnet publish`). If switching application pool bitness resolves the issue, then you were publishing the binaries in the self-contained deployment approach that ties to a certain bitness. Tools like Jexus Manager can detect such issues automatically https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deploying, be sure to set the correct Target Runtime. If you are running on Windows Server, this will likely be win-x64.

If you get this wrong, the application will fail to load, and will give errors similar to what you're reporting.

Comment: We don't usually call that "incorrect version" (because versions are just 3.1/5.0/6.0/7.0) but incorrect bitness (like x86/x64/ARM64).

Comment: Standard was set to x86 changing it to x64 fixed it for me. ty.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is the AppPool. When making a new WebSite in IIS7, for example, it will default to a new v2 AppPool. Select probably your DefaultAppPool instead (v4).

Comment: @JonathanWood this exact error is encountered when the apppool is wrong...